# How to drive a high side mosfet with the L6388E driver?

Tags: mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I've been trying to assemble a circuit to drive an n channel mosfet on a high side mode with this ST L6388E chip [click here for the datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6388e.pdf)
with this circuit:

[image: Circuit]

using 12V of a power supply and 5V from an arduino and when I connect the HIN between GND of 5V the mosfet doesn't seem to do anything.

Any clue to why that happens?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

This driver is a high and low side driver meant to work in continuous switching applications.  It uses a bootstrap technique, meaning that the OUT pin has to be pulled to ground regularly to keep the bootstrap cap charging.

If you try to turn the high side on and keep it on you will not charge the bootstrap cap and therefore will not have enough high side voltage to turn on the FET.  The UVLO on Vboot will not allow the driver to operate.

There are high side FET drivers with charge pumps built in for on/off switch type applications, you might want to look at those.  Here's one example: [Microchip HS driver](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005677A.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

As you have the device connected it can **NEVER** work since the Uv(threshold) is between 7-10.5V.
The device is permanently turned off with a VCC of 5V.
[image]

Once you have sufficient voltage to enable the device, you need to toggle HIN to get the bootstrap action to work.