# Too low output voltage of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, pwm, peltier

I'm trying to create PWM-based control system for Peltier elements, but some troubles was appeared.
The max output voltage is about 8 V, but I was expected 27 V. The PWM frequency is 50 kHz. And I don't know what I do wrong.
[image: Scheme]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I don't know what I do wrong.*

You have used Q1 as a source follower and, in this type of circuit, the source voltage can never be greater than the gate voltage when the MOSFET is conducting. This means that your 27 volts (V2) is always being under-utilized and your circuit will be quite inefficient.

[image]

If you want to use an n channel MOSFET, the voltage at the gate has to be higher than V2 by several volts to ensure that drain and source conduct to each other efficiently.

> *The max output voltage is about 8 V*

That would be about right for this circuit; the peak gate voltage (opto transistor conducting) will be about 11 volts and the source voltage will be between 2 to 4 volts behind this.

Alternatively consider using a p channel MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Previously I have tried to use different variations of common-source scheme, but in this case the output voltage was about 27 V and doesn't changes. So I don't undestand how to increase efficiency of N-channel Mosfet-based scheme. Or is it impossible for this task?

Comment: @Mari it's not impossible. If you always are applying a square wave i.e. the duty cycle doesn't get close to 0 or close to 100% then you can use a technique called bootstrapping. See this for some help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624470/how-is-a-highside-gate-powered-with-a-bootstrap-circuit-and-mosfet-driver

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found a lot of materials about bootstrapping and I'm a little confused. So, I don't sure which one of them will be best: [link](https://ibb.co/GQNWbfb),  [link](https://ibb.co/8j85bcL),  [link](https://ibb.co/SQWyMys).

Comment: I'd use a high-side MOSFET driver chip like the one used here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409950/how-to-drive-a-high-side-mosfet-with-the-l6388e-driver

Comment: And, here's a buyers link to Farnell for their high-side drivers: https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/power-management-ics-pmic/gate-drivers?st=high%20side%20driver&gs=true

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

A [4N35](https://www.tme.com/Document/dcf7498395ab0bb3b43b93aa74a679d1/4N35-VIS.pdf) working into 10kΩ won't switch fast enough, even ignoring the massive capacitive load of the MOSFET gate. Your entire PWM cycle is 20us so you'd like it to switch *much* faster than that.

[image]

1. Replace the 4N35 with a [logic-output optoisolator](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/308/H11L3M_D-2301113.pdf) that is fast enough.
2. Add a gate driver that can conduct large currents to the MOSFET gate. 27V Vgs exceeds the absolute maximum +/-20V for that (and many other) MOSFETs. More like 12V is better. Ones like [this](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/268/MCP14A0901_2_Data_Sheet_DS20006183-3132863.pdf) one are suitable if you reduce the 27V to 12V or so with a regulator etc.
3. Use the MOSFET with a grounded source and put the load in the drain circuit.

Comment: Thank for you answer. I used 27 V, because I need to control chain of Peltier module. And previously I have tried to use different variations of common-source scheme, but in this case the output voltage was about 27 V and doesn't changes.
But maybe optoisolator will enable me to get the best results.

Comment: The 27V is fine for the load, but don't put 27V on the gate relative to the source.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was a little confused. Thanks.